# Why cannot NULL be argument for std::thread's execution function's void* parameter?

Tags: c++, multithreading, null

Here is a minimal case:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <functional>
#include <thread>
void fun(void *args) {}
int main() {
  std::thread thread_id(fun, NULL);
}
```

g++ compiles fail:

```
[firstlove@manjaro misc]$ g++ thread_and_shared_resources.cpp -lpthread -std=c++17
In file included from thread_and_shared_resources.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/thread: In instantiation of 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(void*); _Args = {long int}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]':
thread_and_shared_resources.cpp:6:34:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/thread:120:44: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  120 |           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
      |                                            ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/thread: In instantiation of 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(void*), long int> >':
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/thread:131:22:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(void*); _Args = {long int}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]'
thread_and_shared_resources.cpp:6:34:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/thread:243:4: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(void*), long int> >::__result<std::tuple<void (*)(void*), long int> >'
  243 |    _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Ind...>)
      |    ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/thread:247:2: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(void*), long int> >::__result<std::tuple<void (*)(void*), long int> >'
  247 |  operator()()
      |  ^~~~~~~~
[firstlove@manjaro misc]$ g++ thread_and_shared_resources.cpp -lpthread -std=c++17
In file included from thread_and_shared_resources.cpp:3:
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/thread: In instantiation of 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(void*); _Args = {long int}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]':
thread_and_shared_resources.cpp:6:34:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/thread:120:44: error: static assertion failed: std::thread arguments must be invocable after conversion to rvalues
  120 |           typename decay<_Args>::type...>::value,
      |                                            ^~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/thread: In instantiation of 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(void*), long int> >':
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/thread:131:22:   required from 'std::thread::thread(_Callable&&, _Args&& ...) [with _Callable = void (&)(void*); _Args = {long int}; <template-parameter-1-3> = void]'
thread_and_shared_resources.cpp:6:34:   required from here
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/thread:243:4: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(void*), long int> >::__result<std::tuple<void (*)(void*), long int> >'
  243 |    _M_invoke(_Index_tuple<_Ind...>)
      |    ^~~~~~~~~
/usr/include/c++/9.3.0/thread:247:2: error: no type named 'type' in 'struct std::thread::_Invoker<std::tuple<void (*)(void*), long int> >::__result<std::tuple<void (*)(void*), long int> >'
  247 |  operator()()
      |  ^~~~~~~~
```

Why `NULL` cannot be passed here? the standalone call to `fun` with `NULL` works just fine:

```
fun(NULL) // compiles happily
```

Comment: Try with `nullptr` instead.

Comment: Works fine with nullptr. Also I would recommend using `std::any`.

Answer (score 3):

`NULL` expands to `0` in your implementation, and `0` is an integer, not a pointer.
It is convertible to a pointer in some contexts but not in others; this is an example of the latter.

Use `nullptr`, it solves many similar issues.

Comment: Thanks. I was aware that `nullptr` works fine here. But I cannot see why `NULL` cannot be applied here.

Answer (score 2):

**TL;DR:** `NULL` is legacy C++. In modern C++, use **`nullptr`** as a direct replacement for `NULL` to avoid issues like these.

> Q: *Why `NULL` cannot be passed here? the standalone call to fun with `NULL` works just fine*

1) In glibc, `NULL` in C++ mode is #defined as `0L`<sup>1</sup>

2) `std::thread`'s constructor uses `std::invoke` to *forward* its arguments to the callable argument. When forwarding an rvalue `0L`, it first of all becomes a *variable* (of a reference type).

3) The *null pointer implicit conversion* rule in C++ is specified in [[conv.ptr]/1](https://timsong-cpp.github.io/cppwp/n4659/conv#ptr-1):

> A *null pointer constant* is an integer literal with value zero or a prvalue of type `std​::​nullptr_­t`. A null pointer constant can be converted to a pointer type; the result is the *null pointer value* of that type and is distinguishable from every other value of object pointer or function pointer type. Such a conversion is called a *null pointer conversion*.

That means C++ allows *integral literals* with a value of 0 (thus literally `0`, `0L`, `0u` etc.), but not other integral *values*, to be implicitly convertible to a pointer type:

```
void fun(void* args) {}

int main() {

    fun(0); // OK

    int arg = 0;
    fun(arg); // error: invalid conversion from 'int' to 'void*'

}
```

Now since `std::invoke` is a template, the root cause error, "*invalid conversion from 'long int' to 'void*'*" in your case falls under SFINAE rules and is silently swallowed, leaving you with an obscure error about a problem with `std::thread`s arguments.

The workaround is to use `nullptr` instead of `NULL`.

---

<sup>1</sup> in C mode `NULL` is `(void*)0`, but that is prohibited in C++.